# Segmentation fault during deleting a node from the end of doubly linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to delete  a node from the end of the doubly linked list,but i am getting:

> segmentation fault

i have added different functions to add the node, from beginning , from end , and at any position.I checked the insertion of nodes,its working fine,the DLL is displayed correctly,but when it comes to deleting function,it gives segmentation fault.

```
struct Node {
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    int data;
};
Node* head = NULL;
void insertion_At_End(int element) {
    Node* ptr = head;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = element;
    if(head==NULL) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        while(ptr->right!=NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->right;
        }
        temp->left = ptr->right;
        ptr->right = temp;
    }
}
void insertion_At_Beg(int element) {
    Node* ptr = head;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = element;
    if(head==NULL) {
        head = temp;
    } else {
        temp->right = ptr;
        ptr->left = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
}
void insertion_At_Pos(int element , int position , int length) {
    Node* ptr;
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = element;
    int counter = 1;
    if(position==1) {
        insertion_At_Beg(element);
    }
    else if(position==length) {
        insertion_At_End(element);
    }
    else {
        ptr = head;
        while(counter!=(position-1)) {
            ptr = ptr->right;
            counter++;
        }
        temp->right = ptr->right;
        ptr->right->left = temp;
        temp->left = ptr;
        ptr->right = temp;
    }
}
void deletion_At_End() {
    Node *ptr = head;
    while(ptr->right!=NULL) {
        ptr = ptr->right;
    }
    ptr->left->right=NULL;
    delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: Would you show where you define `head`?

Comment: @ViktorNonov i defined it globally.

Comment: Have you confirmed `ptr->left != NULL`? If it is, it won't have a `->right`

Comment: Okay. Can you post the whole file? Probably it's NULL or points to some inaccessible place in memory.

Comment: @NextInLine i confirmed,ptr->left !=NULL

Comment: You had better tag which programming language you are using

Comment: Did you create `head` using `new Node`? Otherwise `delete` isn't what you want.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. More context may be required to adequately locate the source of your segfault.

Comment: @AndrewFan,sure i edited the question

Comment: It does look like you are missing code to handle the last couple of items in `deleation_At_End` - that is, when the list only has 2 or 1 nodes and you call it, then you have to do something different

Comment: What is the intended usage of this code (IE how is it being called)?

Comment: @AndrewFan, head is initialized globally ,see after structure declaration.

Comment: @NextInLine,i added 6 items in list and called deletion_At_End(), only one time from main method,so i am trying to delete **just** the last node of list,by calling it one time.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. [In my MCVE](https://ideone.com/t7WB0d), `deletion_At_End` the crash is obvious: You can''t test `ptr->right!=NULL` before you've tested `ptr!=NULL`.

Comment: You never check if `head` is null.  Calling `delete_at_End` on an empty list will certainly cause issues.  Same thing with a couple of your other functions -- you failed to check for an empty list.

Comment: The best way to navigate Linked list (and any pointer-driven data structure) bugs is with hand-drawn pictures of what the list should look like at every step and a debugger.

Comment: Your insert_At_End is wrong.  `temp->left = ptr->right` should be `temp->left = ptr`

Answer (score 0):

I get the error if i have only one element in the list. When you have only one element in the list you can not set what it is in its left's right pointing to NULL because it does not exist! This works for me:

```
void deletion_At_End() {
  Node *ptr = head;

  while(ptr->right!=NULL) {
      ptr = ptr->right;
  }
  if(ptr->left == NULL){
      delete ptr;
  }
  else{
      ptr->left->right=NULL;
      delete ptr;
  }

}
```

Comment: you need to make sure `head != NULL` before your `while` loop otherwise `ptr->right` won't work.